# Active Admin filter on two-level deep belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Say a `Person` has many `House` and `House` has many `Door`. (So `Door` has a `house_id` and House has a `person_id` field). I have a list of Doors in Active Admin, in which I want a filter that allows me to choose a person, and show me all doors in all of that person's houses.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Door do
  filter :knob_color
  filter :is_open
  filter :has_window

  filter :house_person      # DOESN'T WORK
  filter :house_person_name # DOESN'T WORK
```

The `Person` model table has a `name` field, so ActiveAdmin should be able to pick that up.

How do I do this?

#### UPDATE

As requested, my situation rephrased in models.

```
# id:   integer
# name: string
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :houses
end

# id:        integer
# person_id: integer
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  has_many   :doors
end

# id:         integer
# house_id:   integer
# knob_color: string
# is_open:    boolean
# has_window: boolean
class Door < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house
end
```

Comment: Please at all relation relevant lines of your Models.

Comment: @TimoSchilling Done.

Answer (score 12):

You need to register a `person` association on `Door` using a `has_one` relation through `house`, and then you can add the filter directly.

```
class Door < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house
  has_one :person, through: :house
end

ActiveAdmin.register Door do
  filter :person
end
```

Comment: Ah, that is an idea I haven't thought of. I will try this right away (and accept your answer if it works as expected, which I would find odd if it didn't). One question out of curiosity: could you apply this technique also if it's a 3-level deep association?

Comment: You can, but bear in mind that each degree of separation requires an additional join. If your tables are large, this can get expensive.

Comment: When I try this, the filter is created, but if I try to run it I get a Module::DelegationError.  Has anyone seen this?