# add a custom Filter Active Admin Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I work on a foodtech project where people can order meals from restaurants; So I have the following relationship in my DB:

each order `belongs_to` a meal and each meal `belongs_to` a restaurant.

I would like to be able to filter by restaurant name on the /admin/orders page. 
Also if possible, I'd like to add a 'restaurant name' column on the page.

Any Idea ?

Comment: OK so I found a solution for the filter problem. Just added `has_one :restaurant, through: :meal` in  model/order.rb and added the filter simply this way: `filter :restaurant`.

Comment: Hi - feel free to add the above as an Answer. you can answer your own questions, and it'll help anyone else who has a similar problem to yours in the future.

Comment: Yes, it was actually just part of the solution, and I expected someone to give the other part as I couldn't find it.

Comment: if there are two parts... then the other part would normally be a separate question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so here's what I finally did; It solves the problem perfectly.

I added `has_one :restaurant, through: :meal` in `model/order.rb` and added the filter simply this way: `filter :restaurant`.

This alowed me to add the restaurant filter.

To get the restaurant column, here's the code:

in admin/order.rb

```
index do
  column("Order", :sortable => :id) {|order| link_to "##{order.id} ", admin_order_path(order) }
  column("pick up time", :pick_up_time)
  column("status", :status)
  column("User", :user_id ) {|order| link_to "#{order.user.first_name}  #{order.user.last_name}", admin_user_path(order.user) }
  column("Meal", :meal)
  column("Restaurant", :restaurant) // This line adds the restaurant column
  column("Created at", :created_at)
  column("Updated at", :updated_at)
end
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715697/active-admin-filter-on-two-level-deep-belongs-to-association ?

Comment: Partially. It is the same problem indeed for the filter, but It does not give further explanation on displaying it as a column in the index table.